# How to override this CSS selector of FireFox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to customize FireFox and override this CSS:[image]

The following code in my UserChrome.css file seems to have no effect.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector should be `.urlbarView.megabar` as it's the same classes on the same element.